# Hosting Vite React project with a relative url

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have the problem that I want users to be able to configure their base path like / , /ui/ . Because the files are generated statically I need to set the url at build time. Here is my vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: './'
})
```

After copying it to the server I get a blank page. I can open every link of the index.html in a new tab and view the source but the page stays empty.